# Fixed points and their continuity

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f : I^2 \to I$ be a continuous map, where $I := [0,1]$ is the unit interval. It is a basic fact that for each $y\in I$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ admits a fixed point. I want to ask whether one can always choose those fixed points as a continuous function of $y$.

**Question:** Does there always exist a continuous path $\gamma : I \to I$ such that $f(\gamma(y),y) = \gamma(y)$ for every $y\in I$?

Comment: Do you mean that $f : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$ and searching for a continuous $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f(g(y), y) = g(y)$ for all $y \in [0,1]$, is it?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I forgot mentioning the range of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: You may find http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6496 interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Let $f(x,0)=0$, $\,f(x,1/2)=x$, $\,f(x,1)=1$,
and define $f(x,y)$ for $0<y<1/2$ and $1/2<y<1$ by linear interpolation
(that is, $f(x,y) = 2yx$ and $f(x,y)=1-2(1-y)(1-x)$ respectively).
Then $g(y)$ would have to be $0$ for $y<1/2$ and $1$ for $y>1/2$,
so $g$ cannot be continuous at $y=1/2$.

Comment: Good example... is there an more strange example such that the fixed point at $y=0$ and the fixed point at $y=1$ stay in different path components of the set of such fixed points?