# Fixed points and their continuity (2)

Tags: gn.general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Yesterday I asked a question about fixed point. Here is the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155553/fixed-points-and-their-continuity).
In summary, the question was,

> Let $f : I^2 \to I$ be a continuous map, where $I := [0,1]$ is the unit interval. It is a basic fact that for each $y\in I$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ admits a fixed point. I want to ask whether one can always choose those fixed points as a continuous function of $y$.
>   **Question:** Does there always exist a continuous path $\gamma : I \to I$ such that $f(\gamma(y),y) = \gamma(y)$ for every $y\in I$?

[Noam D. Elkies](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14830/noam-d-elkies) gave a counter-example as follows.

> Not necessarily.  Let $f(x,0)=0$, $\,f(x,1/2)=x$, $\,f(x,1)=1$,
>   and define $f(x,y)$ for $0<y<1/2$ and $1/2<y<1$ by linear interpolation
>   (that is, $f(x,y) = 2yx$ and $f(x,y)=1-2(1-y)(1-x)$ respectively).
>   Then $g(y)$ would have to be $0$ for $y<1/2$ and $1$ for $y>1/2$,
>   so $g$ cannot be continuous at $y=1/2$.

In that example,$f(x,1/2)$ has more than one fixed point with respect to $x$. Here a new question rises: if the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ admits a **SINGLE** fixed point for each $y\in I$, does the continuous path $\gamma$ exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the answer is "yes". In your settings, the graph of $\gamma$ is the **closed** set $\{(y,x)\,|\,f(x,y)=x\}$, and, at least for **compact** Hausdorff spaces, a map is continuous iff its graph is closed (an easy exercise).

Comment: Wait... Could you please elaborate on "set $\{(y,x)|f(x,y)=x\}$ is closed"?

Comment: This is $g^{-1}(0)$, where $g(x,y):=f(x,y)-x$. Informally, everything given by "continuous" equations and nonstrict inequality is closed: this is almost the definition of continuity.

Comment: Try formally here. Suppose that $A=\{(y,x)|f(x,y)=x\}$ is not closed, then there exist a $(x',y')$ which is not in $A$ but close to $A$, such that $g(x',y')=f(x',y')-x'\neq 0$. Therefore, $g(x,y)$ is not continuous at $(x',y')$, which contradicts with the fact that $g(x,y)$ is continuous within $I^2$.

Comment: @Lansiz: Well, doing serious mathematics, you should forget calculus 101. A function (map) is continuous iff the pull-back of any closed set is closed. This proves pretty much everything. BTW, the "easy exercise" that I mention in my post is easy assuming this definition; another crucial observation needed is that a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff one is closed, i.e., it takes closed sets to closed sets. Without the compactness assumption the characterization of continuity in terms of graphs is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The question when and to what extent there is a continuous/computable map from the parameter to the fixed point is the focus of our paper:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4809

In our terminology, finding fixed points is a weakly computable operation, and a weakly computable operation with unique solutions is already computable (hence in particular continuous). Any other restriction on the fixed points will probably not suffice, as "closed choice for {0,1}" will be reducible to it.